# Conditional memoization?

Tags: python, decorator, python-2.6, memoization, python-decorators

There are plenty of memoization decorators out there, but I'm curious how one would write a memoization decorator which supports arbitrary function signatures, but lets the function decide when to memoize a result? Something like this:

```
def conditional_memoize(f):
    cache = {}
    @wraps(f)
    def conditional_f(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return conditional_f

@conditional_memoize
def my_func(a, b, c):
    if str(a) + str(b) + str(c) in cache:
        return cache[str(a) + str(b) + str(c)]
    res = # compute the result
    if some_arbitrary_condition:
        cache[str(a) + str(b) + str(c)] = res
    return res
```

However, I know this won't work because of the `NameError`. Is there a clever approach to the problem anyway? I could always use a class method and a class cache, just wanted to see if there was a decorator pattern for this.

Comment: How should the function communicate its desire to have its result cached or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the function return both its desired result and a flag indicating whether the result should be cached, or have the wrapper pass the cache object to the function. (Or both!) Either way would work, but I like the first approach better. Maybe something like this...

```
import functools

def conditional_memoize(fn):
    cache = {}

    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        key = args + tuple(sorted(kwargs.iteritems()))
        if key in cache:
            return cache[key]
        result, flag = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        if flag:
            cache[key] = result
        return result

    return wrapper
```

Comment: This effectively changes the result the decorated function returns -- which means they have to be written with the assumption that they'll be decorated.

Comment: Sure. Of course that isn't necessarily a problem; there are plenty of decorators that require such assumptions.

Comment: That assumption is pretty valid. Passing the cache object to the function is all right as well. I wish I had some sort of predicate logic. I wish I was writing Prolog.